# How can I combine 3 VBA subroutines into one?

Tags: vba, conditional-statements, row

The first sub collects all the worksheets of the workbooks that are located in D:\Users\Cons\excel.

Then the second sub looks for the word "filename" in worksheet 2 then copies all the cells below to A2 in worksheet 3.

Finally the last sub should search for the word "apple" in e2:e100 in worksheet 3, and delete every row where "apple" is not found.

I have created 3 buttons and assigned the subs to each one of them. The first 2 runs fine, doing what I want, but when I click on the 3rd button (with 3rd sub behind), nothing happens,

only the first two buttons above are being shifted upwards, don't know why.

How can I combine all the 3 subs into one (that is actually working with a button click)? Thanks in advance!!!

```
Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()

Dim FolderPath As String

Dim Filename As String

Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FolderPath = "D:\Users\Cons\excel\"

Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")

Do While Filename <> ""

Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Next Sheet

Workbooks(Filename).Close

Filename = Dir()

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets(1).Activate

End Sub
```

```
Sub FindInFirstRow()

Dim fCell As Range

Dim strFind As String

Dim wsSource As Worksheet

Dim wsDest As Worksheet

'What shall we look for?

strFind = "filename"

'What sheet are we getting data from/to?

Set wsSource = Worksheets(2)

Set wsDest = Worksheets(3)

Set fCell = wsSource.Range("1:1").Find(what:=strFind, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

If fCell Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "No match found"

Else

'Copy the cells *below* to A2 of destination sheet

Intersect(wsSource.UsedRange.Offset(1), fCell.EntireColumn).Copy wsDest.Range("a2")

End If

End Sub
```

```
Sub SaveSomeRows()

Dim N As Long, L As Long, r As Range

Dim s As String, v As String

Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("e2", ActiveSheet.Range("e100").End(xlUp))

N = r.Count

s = "apple"

For L = N To 1 Step -1

v = LCase(r(L).Value)

If InStr(1, v, s) = 0 Then

r(L).EntireRow.Delete

End If

Next L

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `SaveSomeRows` Sub may not be working because you have `Set r = Activesheet...` Try `Set r = Sheet3...` or `Set r = Sheets("Sheet3")...`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub TheOneSub()
    ConslidateWorkbooks
    FindInFirstRow
    SaveSomeRows
End Sub 

Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()
    ...
End Sub 

Sub FindInFirstRow()
    ...
End Sub 

Sub SaveSomeRows()
    ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub combine_all()
Call ConslidateWorkbooks
Call FindInFirstRow
Call SaveSomeRows

'Runs them sequentially 

End Sub
```

Assign this to a button , this would run (call) the other codes in sequence